# IOS Application Loader error "Unable to Parse application Info.plist for validation"

Tags: ios, loader, info.plist

After cleaning everything in Xcode to Submit my app to iTunes Connect, I've reached an error that I cannot find an answer for.
The full error is:

> Unable to Parse application Info.plist for validation. Please make
>   sure your Info.plist contains no embeddedcontrol characters, is del
>   formed, and is encoded in a UTF-8 compatible encoding.

Im creating the project with UNITY 3D, and everything works okay on my iPod and iPhone, but after I build it to archive and submit either from Organizer or Application Loader I get this error.

Can someone please Help??

Answer (score 3):

I had this error, and it turned out to be an inadvertent space in one of the fields. But the key to resolving these errors is to view the info.plist file in a text editor. By careful examination, you are likely to be able to find the non-conforming character/field.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a BOM character or something else you can't see.
Try converting the document to UTF-8 without BOM
Also, make sure your line endings are all \n (LF) and not \r\n (CRLF). That should fix it.

I'm not sure what text-editors you have, but you can do this with TextWrangler which is Free.

Another possibility is that you have some other special character (like an & or < or >) that it doesn't like, but I'd suspect this isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening your Info.plist in a plain text editor and look for characters that may be out of place.  If you have other similar apps, you can compare both plain text .plist files which may lead you to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, I had a project which exhibited this very error and in my case, swapping "Icon Files (iOS 5)" for the predecessor "Icon Files" made the difference. Remember that the older Icon Files requires the icons to be of the standard naming conventions: Icon.png, Icon@2x.png, Icon-72.png, Icon-72@2x.png, etc.

I can't explain why this change produces the different results which leaves me to believe its a bug in Apple app validation.